# CURL api call with certificate file

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Got from my API providor only .crt file (without private key), i change the name to .pem:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
content
-----ENDCERTIFICATE-----
```

Trying to make an PAI call with a .pem file like this:

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $xml);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("content-type: text/xml"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, '1'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, '2'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, '1');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT, PATH.'/file.pem');
```

i got this error:

```
[curl_error_58] => unable to set private key file: 'file.pem' type PEM
```

**my solution was:**

i ask from my API provider if they have a private key, and they generate one for me, so the error is very simple i actually needed this private key, without this key "CURLOPT_SSLCERT" just not work.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, PATH.'/file.key');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD, '000');
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [unable to set private key file: './cert.pem' type PEM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624704/unable-to-set-private-key-file-cert-pem-type-pem)

Comment: i didn't receive the private key from the api provider, so its not answer yet

Comment: I believe at this point, the error you get is not the file itself but how you get the file, try to make a fresh dir for the `pem` files

Comment: Please note that `CURLOPT_SSLCERT` and `CURLOPT_SSLKEY` don't seem to work with relative paths.